# Insert if pair doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have table with 4 columns: `rowId | userOneId | userTwoId | timestamp`

Is it possible to check whether a pair of users exist and update timestamp if it does? And if it doesn't exist insert new row?

Example of table with expected results:

```
rowId | userOneId | userTwoId |  timestamp
   1        a           b       <timestamp>
   2        a           c       <timestamp>
```

Now if I want to insert into `userOneId` `a` and to `userTwoId` `b`, it will update the timestamp. Also possible is if `userOneId` is `b` and `userTwoId` is `b` update row 1 timestamp as well (would love to see both options - i.e for exact pairs, and for reverse pairs)

Comment: Would it count as a pair if row1 useroneid = 1/usertwoid = 2 and row2 useroneid = 2/usertwoid = 1 ?

Comment: I don't see any reason why not...you're just checking for some data and then running another query. What have you tried so far? What issue are you facing?

Answer (score 2):

THIS ANSWERS THE ORIGINAL VERSION OF THE QUESTION.

I think you want `insert . . . on duplicate key update`:

```
insert into t(useroneid, usertwoid, timestamp)
    values ($userondid, $usertwoid, $timestamp)
    on duplicate key update timestamp = values(timestamp);
```

In order for this to work, you need a unique index on `(useroneid, usertwoid)`:

```
create unique index unq_t_useroneid_usertwoid on t(useroneid, usertwoid);
```

Comment: Thank, that worked, and what if I want it to also consider the "reverse" couple? As P.Salmon suggested